# ASP.NET MVC 5, bootstrap modal popup Not hit Controller method

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using asp.net mvc 5 for my development. I'm try to popup modal with some data to crud operations. I'm try to popup modal with javascript method. After that I click the link my controller method not hit. Screen transform to dark screen.

View :

```
<td class="text-right">
    <a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="javascript:loadEditUser(@item.Id)">
       <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>

    </a>
</td>


<div class="modal fade" id="modalEditUser" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
function loadEditUser(userId) {
        debugger;

        var remoreUrl = "/UserAdmin/Index";

        $('#modalEditUser').modal({
            remote: remoreUrl
        });
    }
```

Partial View :

This is partial View I'm going to popup

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "UserAdmin", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "modalEditUser", OnSuccess = "UserEditSuccess" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    // Web controllers goes here  
}
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult EditUser(int id)
{
    if (id == 0)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var user = UserManager.FindById(id);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var userRoles = UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id);

    return PartialView("_Edit", new EditUserViewModel()
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        UserName = user.UserName,
        Email = user.Email,
        FirstName = user.FirstName,
        LastName = user.LastName,
        phoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber,
        RolesList = RoleManager.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Selected = userRoles.Contains(x.Name),
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = x.Name
        })
    });
}
```

Please help me to sort out this issue. 
Thanks...

Comment: any errors in javascript console?

Comment: No any issue in Console.

Comment: You do not show the controller methods that you are actually using. Best you show the `index` and `create` methods too. Use a tool like Fiddler2 (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check what is being sent and received to/from your server. You can also simple try the URLs in the browser to see if they contain server errors.

Answer (score 0):

try to use server url call from JS

```
var serverUrl = "@Url.Content("~/")";
```

then in Your JS call

```
var remoreUrl = serverUrl + "UserAdmin/Index";
```

Make sure it is

```
var remoreUrl = serverUrl + "UserAdmin/Index";
```

and NOT

```
var remoreUrl = serverUrl + "/UserAdmin/Index";
```

Comment: This is all good advice, but sounds like they are testing in a debug (e.g. localhost) environment, so their existing absolute URLs should work for now. I suspect the problem lays elsewhere :)